# How many numbers higher than average [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, average

I filled an array with 30 random numbers and calculated average. I want to display how many numbers are higher than the average. I tried making a function "aboveAverage" and check if the numbers are higher than the average and than just increase the count "num_over_average++". The problem is I don't know how to pass a value "avg" from function to another function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int n = 30;

void fillArray(int age[], int n) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        age[index] = (rand() % 81) + 8;     
    }
}

void printArray(int age[], int n) {
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        cout << age[index] << endl;
    }
}

double printAverage(int age[], int n) {
    double sum;
    double avg = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + age[i];
    }
    avg = ((double) sum) / n;
    cout <<  avg << endl;
    return avg;
}

void aboveAverage(int age[], int n) {
    double avg;
    int num_over_average = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(age[i] > avg) {
                num_over_average++;
            }
        }
    cout<<num_over_average;
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int age[n];

    fillArray(age, n);
    cout << "array: " << endl;
    printArray(age, n);
    cout << endl;

    aboveAverage(age, n);

    //example: Days above average: 16
}
```

Comment: I suggest you create a new function to *calculate* the average. Then you can use it from both `printAverage` and `aboveAverage`.

Comment: _printAverage_ return the average, just give that value to aboveAverage adding that parameter

Comment: `printAverage` should return a  `double`

Comment: You should change int printAverage into double printAverage. The type that the function rerturns is double and not int.

Comment: `double avg;` -- This is uninitialized in the `aboveAverage` function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's correct, I want to transfer that value from "printAverage" function

Comment: @BostjanBolovi Just have a simple function to compute the average and return it.  A print function's job is to print, not to hold important information (such as the average) your program needs later.  Call it `computeAverage` or something meaningful -- calling it `printAverage` is very misleading.

Comment: @BostjanBolovi BTW, you do the same incorrect things of using uninitialized variables here also in `printAverage`: `double sum;`.  Just to let you know, there is a `std::accumulate` function in C++ that makes errors like this not occur:  `double avg = std::accumulate(age, age + n, 0.0) / n;`  That computes the average, believe it or not.

Comment: I would recommend to use [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) to count the values. Also, is there a reason that you use raw arrays instead of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be a comment, but I don't have enough reps :(

- Change `aboveAverage` to `void aboveAverage(int age[], int n, double avg)`
- Return `avg` from `printAverage` function
- Change the last part of your `main` code to

  ```
  double avg;
  avg = printAverage(age, n);
  aboveAverage(age, n, avg);
  ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do not be afraid, it is an answer, not a comment. You also did 5 seconds before mine, so I delete mine and UV yours ;-) May be propose the OP to also output _endl_ in `cout<<num_over_average;`

Comment: Name should be changed BTW, `double avg = getAverage(age, n); std::cout << avg << std::endl; auto count = aboveNumbers(age, n, avg); //...`.

Answer (score 4):

You have two solutions using your code:

Either you call `printAverage()` to initialise `avg` in `aboveAverage()` :

```
void aboveAverage(int age[], int n) {
    double avg = printAverage();
    ...
}
```

Or you pass the average at parameter of `aboveAverage()` after having computed it with `printAverage()` :

```
void aboveAverage(int age[], int n, double avg) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the standard library you can do that with two lines of code:

```
double average = std::accumulate(std::begin(age), std::end(age), 0.0) / std::size(age);
int above_average = std::count_if(std::begin(age), std::end(age),
    [average](double value) { return average < value; });
```

Okay, you might count that as three lines.

One major advantage of this approach over the code in the question is that you can change the container type to, say, `vector<double>` without having to change any of this code.

Answer (score -1):

Well is pretty simple but dependent on your situation, I'll elaborate.
I'm the case when it's part of a bigger function (do-somthing())
You could calculate the average value like so and pass it to your  "aboveAverage" function and print it:

```
double n_average = printAverage(nArr_ages, n_agesArraySize);

aboveAverage(nArr_ages,  n_agesArraySize, n_averag);
```

Myself would probably rewrite the printAverage function as two functions, one that returns the average value based on the array and another that prints it not both at once because it violates the SOLID principals of a single responsibility and that a function name should reflect exactly what it does, in this case maybe calculateAverage or getAverageAge or any other appropriate name will do (try and name your functions like the english language so your code will be read like a song.

For example:

```
const size_t n = 30;

double calculateAverage(int nArr_ages[], int n_agesArraySize) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    double avg = 0.0;
    for (int indexInArray = 0; indexInArray < n_agesArraySize; indexInArray++) {
        sum = sum + age[indexInArray];
    }
    average = ((double) sum) / n_agesArraySize;
    return average;
}

int aboveAverageCells(int ages[], int n_agesArraySize ) {
    double average = calculateAverage(ages, n);
    int num_over_average = 0;
    for(int indexInArray = 0;  indexInArray < n_agesArraySize; indexInArray++) {
            if(ages[indexInArray] > avg) {
                num_over_average++;
            }
    }
    return num_over_average;
}
```

Now just call them in order, save the returned values to local variables in the main function and print using cout also locally in main.

As a side note next time maybe choose different names for the const and the local functions variable for the array size.

Comment: please never propose to use a global var for that kind of case (I do not DV even that deserves a DV ;-) )

Comment: thats two bad suggestions and no good one. Use references for pass-by-reference and I dont see why one would use a global variable here, what if you compute the average for two datasets? And why would you pass a global variable by reference?

Comment: Note that writing a function that takes a **pointer** to a variable is **not** pass by reference. Writing a function that takes a **reference** is. `void myfunction(int& counter)` takes `counter` by reference.